# Calculating Complex Joint Probability with Dependent and Independent Events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, education

**Can I make the simplification: P(D | A ∩ B ∩ C) = P(D | A) ?**

When : D is independant of B and C but it is dependant of A.

And my question in a more largest way :

**How can I calculate the probability P(A ∩ B ∩ C ∩ D ∩ E ∩ F) when:**

D depends only on A.
E is independent of all events.
F also depends on A.
B and C depends on A and C depends on B also.

Can I just say that : P(A∩B∩C∩D∩E∩F)=P(A)⋅P(B∣A)⋅P(C∣A,B)⋅P(D∣A)⋅P(E)⋅P(F∣A)

Comment: Yes, this works

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Do you know any book or wabsite where I can see the proof of this simplification please ? 
I want to understand a bit better the minimum conditions between each letters to do this :
P(D | A ∩ B ∩ C) = P(D | A)